# Nuxt.js security in production mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Nuxt vuex saves the store state in `window.__NUXT__.state`. Now if you have something like this

`open: true` and based on `true , false` you render some html using `v-if`.

The problem is, you can easily change the `open` property value to whatever you want since it is saved in window object. I couldn't find where normal vuex save the store (if you know please tell me). So this makes `v-if` or anything conditional things is useless. I know I can protect it from server. I am wondering if this is with only nuxt vuex or it has same thing with normal vuex store and other framework like redux?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can not fully protect any conditions checked on the client-side without some server authority.

Comment: "without some server authority." could you please explain a bit? Do you mean server checking on every actions?

Comment: It really depends on how secure you want the app to be, you don't want clients to purchase products with a virtual currency they can easily change in the JS console and not check that on the server. What exactly is your concern? That users will modify the `open` variable and see content they shouldn't see? As long as the content has already been sent to them from the server, if they want, they can see it. But, in the real world for most use cases, normal users don't bother looking at your page source code when using the site.

Comment: Yap got it. Lets say, you have a comment box and you need to be logged in to post a comment. Now you do v-if but they can change the variable so v-if is useless and they can use the form. So in this case, you should check from server. I know this. 

But is normal vuex store changeable like nuxt store? 

Many thanks

Comment: Never rely on the client for security. Assume other people can hack their way into anything they get sent to them. You e.g. save a token in Vuex that is sent to the server to confirm that they are allowed to retrieve information, and you only give them information they are allowes to view. SPA is inherently insecure for these reasons since everything is served to the user directly, with Universal you can serve things only when they get to see it.